# NodeJS - WinstonJS - Clear the log file

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I'm using WinstonJS for logging to a file, and `nodemon` to restart when I update my code.

```
var winston = require('winston');

var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
        new (winston.transports.File)({
            level: 'silly',
            filename: __dirname + '/logs/test.log',
            json: false
        })
    ]
});

logger.log('info', 'something');
```

The log file is being appended to, however when I make a code change and save my file, `nodemon` runs it again and the log file is appended to again. This leads to a log file that just keeps getting longer and longer, and I have to keep manually deleting the contents.

I guess I could do something with the `fs` module, but it would be far nicer to use Winston to say something like `update: replace|append`, but I can't see anything like that available.

Is there any way to clear the log file, so I only have log entries for the last time my code was run..?

Comment: I've found this: https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/examples/create-file.js, which uses `fs` to delete the file before recreating it again. Seems a bit over the top to me though.

Answer (score 15):

The

```
{ flags: 'w' }
```

property on the options object on the new transport is working for me:

```js
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'myLog.txt', options: { flags: 'w' } })
  ]
```

Answer (score 6):

I know this question is a little outdated, but I recently found the answer to this and thought I would share it here for posterity. You can pass `fs.createWriteStream` options to the `File` logger:

```
// Open the file in "write" mode, which truncates first
options: { flags: 'w' },
```